# SQL Server- selecting X amount of days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two Columns Date Created and Date Modified and I need to select all of the items where the date modified is more than 5 day past the created date. 
I can compare the two columns fine but have not found out how to get it to know how many days between the two.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Datediff function from SQL and specify that you want "day" as datepart.
See [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794(v=sql.120).aspx) about this function.

As JamesZ stated, "day" as datepart will only check if we are past 5 days without checking if 5 days really elapsed. So I added both in the select statement. Just use the one you want.

```
  SELECT NbDays        = DATEDIFF(DAY, DateCreated, DateModified),
         *
  FROM [YourTable]
  WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, DateCreated, DateModified) > 5
```

Or

```
  SELECT NbDaysElapsed = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, StartDateTime, ENDDateTime) / 86400000,
         *
  FROM [YourTable]
  WHERE (DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, StartDateTime, ENDDateTime) / 86400000) > 5
```

Comment: Be careful with datediff, it returns **boundaries crossed**, so the difference between 23:59 -> 00:01 is 1, which is fine if that's what you expect.